# StackLauout Label text alignment in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**This is My sample code**

How to fix label2 excessive text below the label1 as per mentioned in the screenshot

> var label1 = new Label()
>               {
>                   Text = "Message:",
>                   MinimumWidthRequest = 100,
>                   TextColor = Color.Red,
>                   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
>                   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
>               };
>
> ```
>         var Label2 = new Label()
>         {
>             Text = "Message message message message message",
>             TextColor = Color.Gray,
>             HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
>             VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
>             LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap
>         };
>
>         var stack = new StackLayout()
>         {
>             Margin = new Thickness(20, 5, 20, 5),
>             Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
>             VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
>             HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
>
>             Children =
>             {
>                 label1, Label2
>             }
>
>         };
>
>         var mainStack = new StackLayout()
>         {
>             Spacing = 0,
>             Children =
>             {
>                 stack
>             }
>         };
> ```

[image]

Comment: Try to use Xaml for designing

Comment: my application designings are fully C# not Xaml. Any suggestion for this issue? @Idris Stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only one way to accomplished this using Formatted text. You needed only one label to do like this:

```
var label1 = new Label ();
var fs = new FormattedString ();
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text="Message:", ForegroundColor = Color.Red});
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { Text="Message message message message message", ForegroundColor = Color. Gray });

label1.FormattedText = fs;
```

Now you add this label in your stack layout

Comment: In my Application the Label2 is bindable text property. Label1 is always static, Label2 is changing as per the binding text. I need to wrap the second label alone.

Comment: Span Text is not bindable.

Comment: UserVoice submissions asking for this. If you also want to see this, please vote.
https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions/suggestions/6256703-extend-span-with-bindable-text-and-tapgesture